# Expect script to simulate SNMP

Tags: bash, snmp, expect

I want to monitor a device that doesn´t support SNMP, so I have tried get a counter via an expect script. This script connects to the device using SSH, logs the output on a file and then it parses the output in order to get the desired counter.

When I execute the script from the console I get the following desired output:

```
root@box:/path# ./GGSN-PDP-Contexts.expect  
.1.3.6.1.4.1.6147.2.1  
Integer32  
310838
```

However, when I try to get the result using snmpget it doesn´t work!

```
root@box:/path# snmpget -m TDP-MIB  -v 2c -c TM_Com_Pub localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.6147.2.1  
TDP-MIB::PDPContextsNumber = No Such Instance currently exists at this OID
```

By the way, this is the relevant configuration at snmpd.conf:
    pass .1.3.6.1.4.1.6147.2.1 /usr/bin/expect /path/GGSN-PDP-Contexts.expect

And this is the expect script that I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f  

# Constants  
set user "user"  
set device "10.10.222.176"  
set pass "blablabla"  
set timeout -1  
set prompt "GGSN-LV02#"  
set file "./GGSN-PDP-Contexts.log"  

# Options  
match_max 100000  
log_user 0  

# Access to device  
spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no $user@$device  
expect "*?assword:*"  
send -- "$pass\r"  

# Commands execution  
expect -exact "$prompt"  
send -- "display pdp-number\r"  
log_file -a $file

# Logging  
expect -exact "$prompt"  
log_file  
send -- "quit\r"  

# Get the value  
set result [exec cat $file | grep "ALL GTP" | cut -d " " -f14]  
set value [format %d $result]  

# Print the value  
puts ".1.3.6.1.4.1.6147.2.1"  
puts "Integer32"  
puts $value  # If I replace the $value with a number, it doesn't work either  

# Erase log file  
exec rm $file  
close
```

Could you bring me any hint? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

In addition, these are the last lines of snmpget's debug output:

```
trace: snmp_comstr_parse(): snmp_auth.c, 135:  
dumph_recv:   SNMP version  
dumpx_recv:    02 01 01 
dumpv_recv:      Integer:       1 (0x01)  
trace: snmp_comstr_parse(): snmp_auth.c, 147:  
dumph_recv:   community string  
dumpx_recv:    04 0A 54 4D 5F 43 6F 6D 5F 50 75 62   
dumpv_recv:      String:        TM_Com_Pub  
trace: _snmp_parse(): snmp_api.c, 4149:  
dumph_recv:   PDU  
trace: snmp_pdu_parse(): snmp_api.c, 4255:  
dumpv_recv:     Command RESPONSE  
trace: snmp_pdu_parse(): snmp_api.c, 4336:  
dumph_recv:     request_id  
dumpx_recv:      02 04 3B 9E CF 74   
dumpv_recv:        Integer:     1000263540 (0x3B9ECF74)  
trace: snmp_pdu_parse(): snmp_api.c, 4347:  
dumph_recv:     error status  
dumpx_recv:      02 01 00   
dumpv_recv:        Integer:     0 (0x00)  
trace: snmp_pdu_parse(): snmp_api.c, 4358:  
dumph_recv:     error index  
dumpx_recv:      02 01 00   
dumpv_recv:        Integer:     0 (0x00)  
trace: snmp_pdu_parse(): snmp_api.c, 4376:  
dumph_recv:     VarBindList  
trace: snmp_pdu_parse(): snmp_api.c, 4406:  
dumph_recv:       VarBind  
trace: snmp_parse_var_op(): snmp.c, 166:  
dumph_recv:         Name  
dumpx_recv:          06 09 2B 06 01 04 01 B0 03 02 01   
dumpv_recv:            ObjID: TDP-MIB::PDPContextsNumber  
trace: snmp_pdu_parse(): snmp_api.c, 4415:  
dumph_recv:         Value  
TDP-MIB::PDPContextsNumber = No Such Instance currently exists at this OID
```

Also, this is my current MIB:

```
TDP-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN  

IMPORTS  
    MODULE-IDENTITY, OBJECT-TYPE, Integer32, enterprises  
                    FROM SNMPv2-SMI  
    OBJECT-GROUP    FROM SNMPv2-CONF;   

TDP MODULE-IDENTITY  
    LAST-UPDATED "201210080000Z" -- 8/oct/2012  
    ORGANIZATION    "TELEFONICA"  
    CONTACT-INFO    "Authors: Hernan Romano / Antonio Ocampo  
                     Email: h.romanoc@pucp.edu.pe / aocampo@pucp.edu.pe"  
    DESCRIPTION     "MIB para gestionar los equipos que carecen de SNMP"  
    REVISION        "201210080000Z" -- 08/oct/2012  
    DESCRIPTION     "Revision 2.1"  
    ::= { enterprises 6147 }    

Nokia                   OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { TDP 1 }  
Huawei                  OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { TDP 2 }  
TDPMIBConformance       OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { TDP 3 }  

ClearCodeGroup1         OBJECT-TYPE  
                        SYNTAX Integer32  
                        MAX-ACCESS read-only  
                        STATUS current  
                        DESCRIPTION "Clear Code Group 1"  
                        ::= { Nokia 1 }  

PDPContextsNumber       OBJECT-TYPE  
                        SYNTAX Integer32  
                        MAX-ACCESS read-only  
                        STATUS current  
                        DESCRIPTION "PDP Contexts Number"  
                        ::= { Huawei 1 }  

TDPMIBGroup             OBJECT IDENTIFIER  
                        ::= { TDPMIBConformance 1 }  

--grupoTDP      OBJECT-GROUP  
--      OBJECTS {  
--              ClearCodeGroup1,  
--              PDPContextsNumber  
--      }  
--      STATUS current  
--      DESCRIPTION "Objetos para el monitoreo de los equipos que carecen de SNMP"  
--      ::= { TDPMIBGroup 1 }  
END
```

Comment: You could try using snmpwalk to diagnose things.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ed. I did the snmpwalk and I got the following result: root@box:/path# snmpwalk -m TDP-MIB  -v 2c -c TM_Com_Pub localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.6147
TDP-MIB::ClearCodeGroup1 = INTEGER: 83
TDP-MIB::ClearCodeGroup1 = INTEGER: 83
Error: OID not increasing: TDP-MIB::ClearCodeGroup1
 >= TDP-MIB::ClearCodeGroup1.

Comment: Try adding -Cc to smnpwalk and running it again - it tells it that it's ok for the OIDs to be out of sequence.

Comment: @ed I got just this output: TDP-MIB::ClearCodeGroup1 = INTEGER: 83
TDP-MIB::ClearCodeGroup1 = INTEGER: 83
TDP-MIB::ClearCodeGroup1 = INTEGER: 83 ....

Comment: Hmmm. I was hoping it would tell you a bit more about PDPContextsNumber. I'm not sure what to suggest after this... maybe someone else will have an idea. It would be useful to include how you intend to have your script executed as a result of the SNMP call.

Comment: Thanks for your time @ed !! Anyone has more ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Finally solved :) The trouble was the path file.

Instead of relative path:
**set file "./GGSN-PDP-Contexts.log"**

I put the absolute path:
**set file "/FULL_PATH/GGSN-PDP-Contexts.log"**

and snmpget works!!

```
root@box:/path# snmpget -m TDP-MIB  -v 2c -c TM_Com_Pub localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.6147.2.1  
TDP-MIB::PDPContextsNumber = INTEGER: 319291
```